# Im trying to send a command list through serial port but only the first line is taken by the device others are ignored

Tags: linux, bash, serial-port

I am trying to send a message including carriage returns (represented without pressing enter) over a serial connection. It works if i press enter with an open serial connection, but I have not found a way to represent the carriage return character successfully within the message body. Need to reprsent the "CR" in txt file.

how could I close the file descriptor (fd) of the serial port before sending next command line?

Note:  the modem documentation says: In order to successfully communicate with modem device, the “$WP” prefix is required when issuing command and the "CR" is required for terminating the command line.

I tried minicom/picocom over /dev/ttyACM0, but same issues only first line of command is performed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I succeeded using minicom with script. 
It was necessary to consider answers sent by the modem to be able to proceed to the following command. What I managed to do with "expect" as following:

```
send <command>
expect "OK"
send <command>
expect "OK"
....
```

You can refer to minicom man page https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-runscript/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `printf`:

```
$ printf 'whatever\r' > /dev/ttyACM0
```

to send the CR

Comment: [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) strongly recommends only answering well-asked questions. Please also see: [Should one advise on off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions) as well as [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)?

Comment: same issue, only taking first line command. Maybe need to disconnect and reconnect simultaneously before sending next line. (?)

Comment: how could I close the file descriptor (fd) of the serial port before sending next command line?